# Angular 2: Add components at specific/nth position dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Unable to add components at specific index. Below the plunker link for example.
    [PlunkerAddRemoveComponents](http://plnkr.co/edit/dl0qdn94i9HfK6dNfWOi?p=preview)

Here, I am able to add components at a specific index at the first time only.

```js
export class AddRemoveDynamic {
    idx: number = 0;

    constructor(private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private _e: ElementRef) { }

    add() {
        this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicCmp, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
            ref.instance._ref = ref;
            ref.instance._idx = this.idx++;
        });
    }
}
```

My Scenario is:

- Click on Add Component button 3 times. It will create 3 rows
  continuously.
- Then click on second row Add button, it will create another row.
- And again click on the same button, it will create component next one
  row

Here, is the problem, I want to create component at every time next to Add button row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated.

I created an example that uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` that allows to add an index where the element should be added:

```
class DynamicCmp {
  _ref: ComponentRef;
  _idx: number;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentResolver, private location:ViewContainerRef) { }
  remove() {
    this._ref.dispose();
  }
  add1() {
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(DynamicCmp).then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
      let ref = this.location.createComponent(factory, 0)
      ref.instance._ref = ref;
      ref.instance._idx = this._idx++;
    });
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvw7aa1psiT6iJnsOytI?p=preview)

Comment: It's working now. Thanks for your help:):):).  Once again Thanks Gunter Zochbauer.